# Variable assigned to instance of jQuery plugin returns 'undefined'

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, undefined

I was looking for a way to create a countdown timer plugin for a project I'm working on, and did so using the template found here:
http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/jquery-plugin-boilerplate-oop/.

My plugin works as it should, and I assign it to a variable like:

```
var timer1 = new $.timer({
    option1: true, 
    callback1: function(){
        //do something
    }
});
```

but when I later on go to check the value of that variable, it returns undefined rather than an object, as I would expect. I can use this same variable, however, to access the public methods of my timer:

```
timer1.set(10);
```

and it will set the timer.

But trying to return the object within the variable 'timer1' returns undefined instead.

Here is the basis of the code (unfortunately my employer restricts me from posting it as it is - I have had to cut out the actual method code):

```
;
(function($) {

    $.timer = $.timer || {};
    $.timer = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            option1: false,
            option2: false,
            callback1: function() {
            }
        };
        var plugin = this;
        plugin.settings = {};

        //local variables

        var sampleVar = 0;

        //constructor

        var init = function() {
            plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
            return plugin;
        };

        //private methods

        var fire = function() {
            //do something here
            plugin.settings.callback1.call(plugin);
        };

        var updateTimer = function() {
            //do something here
        };

        var reset = function() {
            //do something here
        };

        //public methods

        plugin.set = function(time) { 
            //do something here
        };

        plugin.start = function() {
            //do something here
        };

        init();
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: My timer works fine, but if I try to check if anything is assigned to the variable timer1 (by console.log()), rather than returning an object, it returns undefined. But I can still use this variable to control the timer...

Comment: So, for some reason this has to do with the whole chainability thing I've got going on. I initialise the timer, set it and start it at once, and for some reason doing this returns 'undefined' instead of the object. If I do these in separate steps, it works fine.